# Modeling investment decisions with ML / Econometrics

Tags: finance, quantitative, modelling

I was given the task to decide whether it is a good time to invest into a certain stock index (e.g. S&P 500) or not given a 6 months Investment horizon. The goal is to get one of the following answers: "invest" or "don't invest"

Explanatory variables should be macroeconomic ones such as VIX, EURUSD,10y Treasury yield etc. Apart from that, I am quite free to choose a model.

I was wondering what would be the best approach to tackle the problem. I was considering using some a classificstion algorithm like K nearest neighbors where the features are the above mentioned data (VIX etc) and the label is the performance of the index 6 months from now.

Do you think that's possible or would it make more sense to use a standard econometric model?

Do you have some references where something similar has been done? I am currently a little lost where to start.